# Avoid double quotes around column while spooling to csv from oracle

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to export a select query output to text file using spool. The output by default adds double quotes around the column. How to Prevent it?
The query returns only one column.

Ideally i need to remove headers as well as the double quotes from the output. below is the script file i use in oracle Developer. but heading is also not removed.

```
set echo off
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET COLSEP ''
spool 'D:\public\cvs_txPCG.txt'
select /*csv*/ 
pcg from temptx;
spool off;
```

output

```
"PCG"
"76259737020150320000504281565213310052440093515652109.2909.290101"
"19519905620160502000504283153419040044861008644759203.3903.390101"
"49424051620160220000504284594314590009220713032964404.3804.380202"
"88761197020151025000504284594315180036700812132964401.9901.990101"
```

Comment: @Plirkee. Does it work in Developer UI? I have access to only Developer. Not Sql Plus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get rid of the double-quotes with the `/*csv*/` directive. The slightly more convenient way of doing this now is with the `sqlformat` command, but even with `sqlformat delimited` [you have to have the string enclosed](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/#div-comment-109268).

Using CSV format for a single column seems rather pointless anyway though, *unless* you have delimiters in your string you want to escape. If you are really exporting that one column and don't have delimiters then just leave out the `/*csv*/` directive. If you have multiple columns or strings that may contain delimiters then the enclosures are useful to stop those delimiters being misinterpreted when opening in Excel or some other external tool.

If you really want CSV format without enclosures you can either build up the output manually by concatenating the column(s) with comma literals, which still allows you to spool to a file:

```
select pcg ||','|| some_other_col ||','|| etc from ...
```

Or you can run the query using Run Statement (Ctrl-Enter) and then export the results from the data grid, from the context menu that appears when you right-click on the output. When you export and choose CSV or delimited format you can choose whether to include the header and which delimiter and enclosures to use - and you're allowed to choose 'none'. If you don't want to set that on each export you can set it as a default, from Tools->Preferences:

[image]

You can't do it with the `/*csv*/` directive or `sqlformat csv` though.

Comment: Perfect !. I removed CSV directive and both headers as well as the double quotes are gone. Thanks a lot. But i am getting a message at the last row which says "n rows selected ". Can i avoid that too?

Comment: Got that too . add "set feedback off"

Comment: Very annoying that you can select NONE from here, but you can't specify that in SQLcl's "SET SQLFORMAT DELIMITED" or "SET SQLFORMAT csv" commands, but you could in SQL *PLus's "SET MARKUP CSV". No consistency. Maddening. One thing works here, doesn't work there.

Comment: @TheRizza - yes... as an alternative you can use `unload` with `set loadformat enclosures off` - as shown recently [on the SQLcl forum](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/sqlformat-delimited-no-enclosure-4222), but that has to write to a file (not screen/worksheet), and only works for tables, not views.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is too old but got the answer with my search today, simply use

```
set markup csv on quote off
select 1 id, 'Venkat' name from dual;
```

Output will be

```
ID,NAME
1,Venkat
```

Didn't even think of any other SET commands

Comment: You didn't mention we need SQL*PLus 12.2 to use this. Wouldn't work in SQL CL. Thank you! It's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Tried that but didn't work in SQLDeveloper 12.1 (SP2-0158: unknown SET option "markup")

Comment: @mmo, Probably You are on the lower version that don't support this command but this works. I don't remember the version I used when I actually posted the answer, neither OP mentioned his version. You can download the latest version of SQLDeveloper from Oracle website at no cost

Answer (score 0):

If the double quotes are part of the data you can use the trim() function to remove them.

```
select /*csv*/ 
trim(both '"' from pcg) as pcg from temptx;
```

Oracle documentation for the trim function:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm

Comment: Double Quotes are not part of data.